# USB drive not detected

Tags: usb, udev, usb-drive, block-device

I had an USB on a headless raspberry pi running debian, but after rebooting without unmounting (there were programs running on the mounted folder), I couldn't use the USB anymore. The following is the output on my Ubuntu 18.04 of:

`lsusb`, the drive is there:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 090c:3000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.)
```

`ll /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Silicon_Motion_Inc._USB_MEMORY_BAR-0\:0`, shows the link to `/dev/sdb`

```
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Silicon_Motion_Inc._USB_MEMORY_BAR-0:0 -> ../../sdb
```

`file /dev/sdb`:

```
/dev/sdb: block special (8/16)
```

However, `mount /dev/sdb folder` shows:

```
mount: /home/steamos/TOSH: no medium found on /dev/sdb.
```

I found the following information that looks like the problem:
`blockdev --report /dev/sdb`:

```
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw   256   512  4096          0               0   /dev/sdb
```

and `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb` if can help:

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/block/sdb':
KERNEL=="sdb"
SUBSYSTEM=="block"
DRIVER==""
ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
ATTR{capability}=="51"
ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
ATTR{events}=="media_change"
ATTR{events_async}==""
ATTR{events_poll_msecs}=="-1"
ATTR{ext_range}=="256"
ATTR{hidden}=="0"
ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"
ATTR{range}=="16"
ATTR{removable}=="1"
ATTR{ro}=="0"
ATTR{size}=="0"
ATTR{stat}=="       0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0"
```

So the problem is with device size and `ATTR{stat}== 0 0 0 0...`.

`dmesg -w` shows:

```
[33490.303624] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 5
[33510.836920] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[33511.432630] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=3000
[33511.432634] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[33511.432636] usb 1-7: Product: SM3255AA MEMORY BAR 
[33511.432638] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Silicon Motion,Inc. 
[33511.438206] usb-storage 1-7:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[33511.438372] scsi host10: usb-storage 1-7:1.0
[33512.473781] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USB MEMORY BAR   1000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[33512.474222] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[33512.474975] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

How can I recover the files on the USB?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I recover the files on the USB?

Even though I hope that you will be able to fully save the drive, I would like  to answer this question.

## 1. Create an image of the drive

This is a pretty important step that will prevent you from doing even more damage than good. This is a good idea even before you proceed to try and fix the drive. The file recovery we will do later will be performed on the disk image, instead of the real disk. To create a disk image, simply issue the following command: (Status flag is optional, it shows the progress statistic as `dd` is running)

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=sdb.img bs=1M status=progress
```

## 2. Perform file recovery

There are plenty of recovery applications, personally I find that `photorec` and `foremost` work best. `photorec` is usually part of the `testdisk` package. On debian, you can install both as followed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install testdisk foremost
```

**a) Photorec**

Simply run `$ photorec sdb.img` now to open up photorec's interactive interface.

Hit return (`[Proceed]`) to select the disk image. In the next screen, you're asked to select a partition. If photorec finds the correct partitions, you can select the one you want to recover the files from here. If it doesn't detect the partitions properly, simply select `No partition [Whole disk]` and hit return again to perform the `[Search]`. Once selected the filesystem type in the next screen, you need to select a directory in which the recovered files should be saved. Confirm with `C`.

Once it's done, proceed with step 3.

**b) Foremost**

While photorec works by trying to find "data blocks" of the drive and media within using [file carving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_carving), foremost does it a bit differently. It's still using the file carving concept but it ignores the type of underlying filesystem and directly works by copying segments of the drive into your RAM, which is then being scanned for file header types. Foremost comes with a lot of built-in headers to recover most types of common files, if you want to add custom headers/footers to detect less common file types, foremost offers you this ability.

To run foremost using the default options on the image, run the following command:

```
$ foremost -i sdb.img -v
```

That will save all recovered files into `output` (new directory that foremost will create). You can specify another output directory using the `-o` flag, and `-a` to ignore errors/save corrupted files.

## 3. Filter the recovered files

This is optional, but sometimes you are only interested in specific types of files, or even worse: Recovery tools give you a million of files out of which thousands appear to be, for example, a JPEG file, but in reality it's just a corrupted file and not a picture at all. To filter these out you can use [this](https://superuser.com/a/1342003/926024) answer I gave to another question on SuperUser.

Comment: I had the same idea of taking a snapshot of the usb, but unfortunately, this is the output `dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': No medium found`.

Comment: What happens if you try `dd if=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Silicon_Motion_Inc._USB_MEMORY_BAR-0\:0 of=sdb.img bs=1M` ?

Comment: Same thing, `dd: failed to open '/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Silicon_Motion_Inc._USB_MEMORY_BAR-0:0': No medium found`.

Comment: Does `fdisk -l` detect the disk at all? If not: Unplug the drive, run `dmesg -w` and plug it back in. Update your OP to add the relevant lines please.

Comment: Updated, and no `fdisk -l` doesn't detect it. That's the thing.

Comment: The `dmesg` output looks perfectly fine, so does `file`'s output. `/dev/sdb` must exist. What does `ls -l /dev/sdb` say? Maybe it's an issue with permissions. Have you tried `fdisk -l` and similar as root user? You could also try running `testdisk` as root user, then hit `[Preceed]` to get a list of all disks. Does that show your disk? If yes, you can use testdisk to attempt a partition hunt and restore the partition table. (If that's broken)

Comment: `brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 iul 30 22:21 /dev/sdb`, nothing unusual. No luck with `testdisk`. Thank you.

Comment: You can try a different PC, but if that does nothing too I think it's a hardware failure. Really surprises me how the `dmesg` output looks perfectly fine though...

Comment: I 'broke' the USB on the raspberry pi running debian. All the tests and commands were from my Ubuntu 18.04.... Thank you anyway.

Comment: I am looking again at the output of `blockdev --report /dev/sdb`. Do you know if the size of the USB can be forced manually to a value? It's possilble that `dd` and others are expecting a device size, but actually it's `0`.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue since `dd` reports that it doesn't find an medium at all. I'm not aware of a method to force a blockdev size either, you should ask those chinese guys selling "2 TB USB drive"s. On a serious note though, have you ever tried it under windows? I remember I had a usb drive (3.0) before that suddenly stopped working on linux one day, completely. It just won't be detected. Maybe it was similar to your issue, I barely had any linux knowledge back then. However, it still worked fine under windows 7 and XP.